# Chrome changed its color, why? How can have back the original?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, colors

**Context**

I am using latest Chrome in Windows 10 Desktop. Chrome sometimes changes its color by itself, (see picture) but so far closing Chrome window and reopening it gave me back the original white. It was annoying but I could handle this minor inconvenience. However today morning nothing helps.

**Note:** *This is clearly not a display color problem, see the original white is showing up in the attached picture, and all other applications are rendering correctly.*

**What I've tried so far**

- Settings/Advanced/Reset
- Close Chrome and reopen
- Restart Windows...

**Question**

How can I get back the original white?

[image]

Comment: I really do not understand what's wrong with this question. Is it inappropriate in this forum, or too broad, or is it so evident that unnecessary to ask? I took the time and formed a structured question, what is missing?

Comment: Perhaps you have inadvertently activated the night light settings. Check it in Settings > System > Display

Comment: I can not find such a setting, neither under Settings -> System, neither by searching withing settings for 'Display', or 'night'. Anyway I had reset all settings with no effect.

Comment: Do you have any extensions or themes installed? Have you tried changing your theme in Windows to the default?

Comment: @Sonickyle27: No I have no themes, no color extensions. Only Adblock and a Cache Killer. Anyway after Reset all was disabled and the color remained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an ICC profile thing in **Windows 10**

**Please note:** ***No other browser was affected, neither other applications***, so it's not clear is it a Chrome bug, or Windows bug or just an unfortunate data error.

Also note: I did not even know what is ICC profile a week ago, and did not set it, configured it.
I also did not install and use any photography related applications, like PhotoShop, they were not installed and uninstalled on my computer.

---

After two weeks of suffering from the effect and spending literally hours of uninstalling, wiping Chrome, I got an idea and "recalibrated" colors (not on my monitor, in Windows. I did not have to adjust anything except of gamma a bit, but the gamma was **already gray** so individual colors **not** adjusted separately. After clicking through the Windows wizard and doing seemingly nothing, the Chrome issue disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! This solved my problem. But mine fixes by DISABLING the hardware acceleration and not enabling. (not sure if that was what you meant)

[edge left and chrome right (before fixed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YtPI.jpg)

[edge left and chrome right (fixed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7beEw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue where Google Chrome window color got changed to dull cream color. All the content, video, images in Chrome changed the color tone.

After some trial & error, I set the below settings in Chrome. The Issue got fixed.

Google Settings -> System -> Use hardware acceleration when available